# Laravel 9 Foreign Key Constraints issue on INSERT

Tags: sql, laravel, migration, constraints, laravel-9

I tried following what the documentation says here regarding foreign keys:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

I have 3 tables that need to be connected to each other:

**roles:**

[image: 1]

**users:**

[image: 2]

role_user:

[image: 3]

I am having some issues in my `role_user` this is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`usersexam`.`role_user`, CONSTRAINT `role_user_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

this is it's migration: (tried to follow the laravel docs syntax)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    });
}
```

then here is my insert query:

[image: 4]

What did I do wrong in the process? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert data into the `roles` and `users` table before inserting anything into the `role_user` table

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an id in the pivot table that **does not exist** in the parent table. Make sure the value that you are inserting into the foreign keys exists in the parent table(s).

You're getting this error because you're trying to insert a row to the `role_user` table that does not have a valid value for the `role_id` field based on the values currently stored in `roles` table.

So what you need to do is insert data into both `roles` and `users` tables first.